# Is Fermi level always constant?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential

Let us imagine a heterojunction with one side called A and the other side called B. Both A and B are n type materials with different doping levels. A has a higher conduction band energy than B, but B has a higher Fermi level. Can electrons diffuse from B to A even though A has a much higher conduction band energy and B has a higher Fermi level?
Will thermal equilibrium be achieved in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in thermal equilibrium the fermi level should be constant. The situation you describe is similar to that of a n n+ junction and if you had the same material with different doping concentration you would have some band bending and the establishment of a small drift and and a small diffusion current opposing each other.

It is the same situation with the heterojunction. You will have some band bending due to the difference between fermi levels, but you will have addition discontinuities introduced due to the difference in band gaps. Depending on the relative magnitudes of the band gaps at the junction you can have the discontinuity be opposed to the band bending.

The fermi level is a statistical quantity, and if I understand your question in your case a small number of electrons would need to diffuse to the wider gap side.